# Ignoring / Not Mapping certain POCO properties in NEST 2.0

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am having a hard time finding good detail on NEST 2.0, the wrapper for Elasticsearch 2.2 I am using. My question is this: Can I do a bulk insert on an object (class with public data members) and map that to Elasticsearch where only the mapped fields between my C# class and the ES server mapping will save? And it will not add the additional fields in my class I do not want?

Right now I have a class of with strings and doubles and lists of other classes in it. I want to save the strings and doubles, but NOT include the Lists on my bulk inserts to Elasticsearch. It wants to save every piece of data in every field of my class. Is there a class member attribute or some other way to say "do not add this field if it has no mapping" that I have missed? I hope so.

Comment: May you share your current code which configure index mapping? Do you use attribute based mapping?

Comment: This is a closed network system so I cannot post code.

Comment: Is there any way the title can be more verbose?

Comment: @theMayer I've given it a clearer title

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can ignore properties of your POCO in a number of ways with NEST 2.x. Let's use the following POCO as an example

```
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[ElasticsearchType(Name = "company")]
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [String(Ignore = true)]
    public string IgnoreViaAttribute { get; set; }

    public string IgnoreViaSettings { get;set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string IgnoreViaSerializerSpecificAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

1.Using the `Ignore` property on a derived `ElasticsearchPropertyAttribute` type (in our example, `StringAttribute` on `IgnoreViaAttribute` property) applied to the property that should be ignored on the POCO

2.Using the `.InferMappingFor<TDocument>(Func<ClrTypeMappingDescriptor<TDocument>, IClrTypeMapping<TDocument>> selector)` on the connection settings

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    .InferMappingFor<Company>(i => i
        .Ignore(p => p.IgnoreViaSettings)
    );

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

These settings are cached per instance of `ConnectionSettings`.

3.Using an ignore attribute applied to the POCO property that is understood by the `IElasticsearchSerializer` used, and inspected inside of the `CreatePropertyMapping()` on the serializer. In the case of the default `JsonNetSerializer`, this is the Json.NET `JsonIgnoreAttribute`. In our example, this is demonstrated by the attribute applied to the `IgnoreViaSerializerSpecificAttribute` property.

Comment: documentation is now up on elastic.co - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/auto-map.html#ignoring-properties

Answer (score 1):

What I found by digging around a bit and testing a small class is that the following structure did indeed hide the attributes when you post a class with NEST 2.0 C#. If you do this just above the class member you wish to ignore when doing a bulk add that covers it.

```
[String(Ignore = true)]
```